# Uploading image with mongodb node.js and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to be able to upload an image from his computer to the server and the image to be saved in my mongoose schema and also be able show it back to the user. Here is my schema

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  image: String,
  body: String,
  category: String,
  author: {
  id: {
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: "User"
  },
  username: String
  }, likes: [
  {
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: "likes"
  }
  ],
  comments: [
  {
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: "Comment"
  }
],
created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Blog", blogSchema);
```

Comment: are you using a framework for the backend ? express maybe ? or just plain-node ?

Comment: i am using ejs and express.

Comment: ok in the past I used https://npms.io/ to search for library but it seems to have issues for now, once those issues disappear I recommend you to use it as I recall I found good upload libraries for express

Comment: However, formidable(a library) can be used for image upload, as for the storing it in database you can store only the image path, now mongodb has `GridFS` but that's for distributing large files(very large ones) into chunks which I doubt you'll need for simple image files

Comment: `multer` is also a popular one